# I can not GET the time exposure in a CMOS

Tags: matlab, time

I'm working with a thorlabs camera (DDC3240M). I can use the manual commands to get an image, display the image, select the number of bits and set the exposure time. But to be sure of the exposure time that I SET in CMOS I realy would like to GET the time exposure. In the manual suggests using the following command:

Syntax: cam.Timing.Exposure.Get

Description: Returnsthe current set exposure time (in ms)

So, according to the camera manual with this command I would be able to GET the exposure time in ms. But when I use this the only response that I get from the command line is
ans = Success

And this type of response according to the manual means that the command has been successfully executed.
But I can not see the value. I used functions to show the value as (dfprintf) but Ican not see the value.

```
% Add NET assembly
% May need to change specific location of library
NET.addAssembly('C:\Program Files\Thorlabs\Scientific Imaging\DCx Camera Support\Develop\DotNet\uc480DotNet.dll');
%Some parametres for the camera
exposure_ms = input('What is the exposure time in ms:');
gain = input('What is the gain:');
% Create camera object handle
%cam = uc480.Camera;
cam = uc480.Camera;
% Open the 1st available camera
cam.Init(0);
% Set display mode to bitmap (DiB)
cam.Display.Mode.Set(uc480.Defines.DisplayMode.DiB);
% Set color mode to 8-bit RGB
% cam.PixelFormat.Set(uc480.Defines.ColorMode.RGBA8Packed);
cam.PixelFormat.Set(uc480.Defines.ColorMode.SensorRaw8);
%Sequence of images

   % Set trigger mode to software (single image acquisition)
cam.Trigger.Set(uc480.Defines.TriggerMode.Software);
% Allocate image memory
[~, MemId] = cam.Memory.Allocate(true);
%Set the parametrs for the camera
cam.Timing.Exposure.Set(exposure_ms);
cam.Gain.Hardware.Scaled.SetMaster(gain);

% Obtain image information
[~,Width, Height, Bits,~] = cam.Memory.Inquire(MemId);

tic
for t=1:100
% Acquire image
cam.Acquisition.Capture(uc480.Defines.DeviceParameter.Wait);
% Copy image from memory
[~, tmp] = cam.Memory.CopyToArray(MemId);
% Reshape image
Data = reshape(uint8(tmp), [1, Width, Height]);
% Data = Data(1:3, 1:Width, 1:Height);
Data = permute(Data, [3,2,1]);
image(Data); drawnow;
end;
toc


% Rename 
%eval(sprintf('Data%d=Data;',k));
% himg = imshow(Data);
% Save the image and Close camera
dlmwrite('C:\Users\DanielleCristina\Desktop\AprendendoMatLab\DadosMatLab\data3.txt',Data,'Delimiter','\t');
cam.Exit;
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! CCD tag is intended for questions related to HL7 Continuity of Care Documents (medical) only. Please remove the irrelevant tag from your question.

Answer (score 0):

`cam.Timing.Exposure.Get` returns two parameters. The first one is a flag which is the one you are reading and if you want to get the exposure value try using.

```
[a,b] = cam.Timing.Exposure.Get;
```

`b` will hold the value of the exposure time (in ms).